# New Thunderbird (version 60+) to show emails' date with four-digit again?

Tags: email, thunderbird, date

Recently in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS we got a new Thunderbird version, jumping from version 52 something to now version 60.2.1

In the e-mail section which lists all e-mails, as well as in the individual e-mail's header, the date is now two-digit only compared to four-digit in the previous Thunderbird versions.

Can we somehow get four-digit dates again?

"about:config" doesn't seem to list a variable concerning such "date" settings.
Also my Ubuntu is set to four-digit dates.

Comment: Open Thunderbird Preferences, go to the Advanced tab, and try switching between the options under "Date & Time Formatting".

Comment: Thanks Pomsky for your hint. I didn't know it.
Unfortunately switching from "system setting" to "localised setting" doesn't change the two-digit to a four-digit year display in the e-mails list and in the e-mail header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Thunderbird version 91, you can customise the date formats using the config editor.  Full instructions at the end of https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/customize-date-time-formats-thunderbird

Summary:

- edit -> preferences, scroll to the bottom and click the button that says "Config Editor..."
- create a new preference called intl.date_time.pattern_override.date_short with type string
- set the value to dd-MM-yyyy (or MM-dd-yyyy or yyyy-MM-dd if you prefer a different order)

Comment: Great news! Deo gratias,thank you, Alexander.

Comment: I felt a little silly answering such an old question, but it shows up in google search results, so I thought it might be useful to someone.  Glad you're still around to share the joy!